# Pick latest node from taxonomy term supplied in node

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have 2 contenttypes.

Productpage and Blogpost.

The blogposts uses taxonomy (blogcategories) and is only connected to 1 term.

Now I want to use a dropdown on the productpages where I select a term (term reference) that I want to get the latest post from.

How can I accomplish this? I can't use the term reference field as a relationship in views so I don't know what to do.

Please help.

Kind regards,
Daniel Lundahl

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the phrase "where I select a term that I want to get the latest post from." What are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: I want to select a blogcategory term on my productpage. When I'v selected a term, I want a view to display the latest blogpost connected to that term.

Comment: With Ajax, onto the productpage form, that's it ?

Comment: I'm selecting term with a dropdown list

Comment: I just found the problem. The term reference on the blogposts is displayed as term ID. The term reference on productpages is displayed as term Name. So they don't "match". Anyone know why they display different things? They are exactly the same fields.

Comment: See the display of your content type